# How to remove html encoding from a string in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a very simple requirement. I have two strings as follows :

```
htmlStr = "&lt;strong&gt;News Body&lt;/strong&gt;";
htmlStr1 = "<strong>News Body2</strong>";
```

I use innerHTML of div tag to display these strings on a html page

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlStr"></div>
<div [innerHTML]="htmlStr1"></div>
```

Output I get is

[image]

My expected output is :

[image]

How do i remove html encoding from htmlStr?

Comment: Trying to achieve it using angular 4 :)

Comment: There are so many answers, read all, you found your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct. You should replace the special characters with the brackets by e.g.

```
strHtml = strHtml.split(‘&lt;’).join(‘<‘).split(‘&gt;’).join(‘>’)
```

Comment: Is there any dynamic way of doing it? There might be other html encoded characters in the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try pipe for dynamic encoding html string

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e5vpxs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) - it's working correct do like this